# PHP Echo with a select list syntax error

Tags: php, mysql, drop-down-menu, syntax-error

Can someone help me...
I need to echo an option list, with selected option from database, within an echo but i am getting a syntax error

Does anyone know how to do this, if so, code to edit is below if possible?

the echo starts

```
echo('
    <option value="0">'?><?php if($fDetail['arrange']=="opening") echo "selected="selected"; ?>'opening</option>
    <option value="1">'?><?php if($fDetail['arrange']=="closing") echo "selected="selected"; ?>'closing</option>
```

I have done as Elias has suggested, however now echo(' alot of table details...then i come to a drop down menu i need to prefill from database entries, either opening or closing and a few more, just putting 2 for examples sake however there are 5....

```
<select name="fDetails['.$mCount.'][arrange]" id="itemArrange'.$mCount.'" onKeyPress="return disableEnterKey(event)" >
<option value="0">'?> <?php if($fDetail['arrange']=="1") {echo 'selected="selected"' Opening</option>
<option value="1">'?> <?php if($fDetail['arrange']=="2") {echo 'selected="selected"' Closing</option>
</select>
```

### STAGE 2

I now have the following code with no syntax errors, however, an output issue...
Just to make it easier, here comes full code from the start of the echo

```
            echo('
    <tr>
    <th colspan="3"><label>Item '.$mCount.'</label></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td colspan="1"><label for="fDetailTitle'.$mCount.'">Item Title:</label></td> 
    <td colspan="2"><input type="text" size="25" name="fDetails['.$mCount.'][title]" value="'.$fDetail['title'].'" id="fDetailTitle'.$mCount.'" onKeyPress="return disableEnterKey(event)" />
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td colspan="1"><label for="fDetailArtist'.$mCount.'">Item location:</label></td>
    <td colspan="2"><input type="text" size="25" name="fDetails['.$mCount.'][location]" value="'.$fDetail['location'].'" id="fDetailArtist'.$mCount.'" onKeyPress="return disableEnterKey(event)" />
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td colspan="1"><label for="fDetailitemStatus'.$mCount.'">item Status:</label></td>
    <td colspan="2">
    <select name="fDetails['.$mCount.'][arrange]" id="itemArrange'.$mCount.'" onKeyPress="return disableEnterKey(event)" >
<option value="0". $fDetail['arrange']=="Entry" ? 'selected="selected"':'' .'>Entry</option>
<option value="1". $fDetail['arrange']=="Exit" ? 'selected="selected"':'' .'>Exit</option> 
 </select>
</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td colspan="1"><label for="itemNotes'.$mCount.'">item Notes:</label></td>
    <td colspan="2"><input type="text" size="25" name="fDetails['.$mCount.'][notes]" value="'.$fDetail['notes'].'" id="itemNotes'.$mCount.'" onKeyPress="return disableEnterKey(event)" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>'
);
```

when looping, i am getting repeated >closing>closing>closing>closing>closing>closing at the top of the screen, and all fields become itemNotes, the rest have gone, i presume a missing / etra needed ' or " ?

Comment: Where is the rest of your php code? And please copy-paste the exact error.

Comment: You still have invalid syntax (`<select...` is being `echo`-ed, but the expression passed to `echo` can't contain `if` statements (As I've explained in my answer). The resulting markup will still be invalid, _and_ your `if` statements are now invalid, too (no closing `}`, no semicolon, no closing `?>` before `Opening</option>`...

Comment: Full code added, this is the first stage that, for every item already ordered, i need its own title, location, status and notes, the next else if, is to add a new one, then a jquery statement to add more if required, once i have this bit done i'll be sending someone a pallett of heroes lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a tad unclear what your code actually looks like, but if it looks like this:

```
echo ('<option value="0">'?><?php if (<condition>) echo 'string';?>
```

You're in a world of trouble. `echo` is not a function, so don't use brackets (though brackets can be used, it's just code-smell, IMHO).
The string you're pushing to the `echo` construct is just that: a string, a single expression, that cannot contain separate statements (like an `if` branch). Either way, your syntax is invalid. Of course, a ternary is allowed, but even if you get that to work there are plenty more issues to fix.

Your resulting HTML will be invalid, or at least: not what you want, because you're closing the `<option>` tag before echoing the `selected` attribute:

```
echo '<option value="0">'
```

So the resulting markup will be:

```
<option value="0"> selected="selected"opening</option>
```

Keep things simple, why not simply write:

```
?>//close php
<option value="0" <?php if (<condition>) echo 'selected="selected"';?>>value</option>
```

Just putting out raw html, without the need to `echo` it.
You could shorten this down further using PHP's short echo tags (not the same as short tags!), and a ternary:

```
<option value="0" <?= <condition> ? 'selected="selected"' : '' ?>>value</option>
```

Syntax highlighting would've told you that:

```
echo "selected="selected";
```

Is a problem, it should've been either

```
echo "selected=\"selected\"";
//or
echo 'selected="selected"';
//or
echo "selected='selected'";
```

I have a slight (perhaps personal) preference for the second of the valid examples. In part because double quote-delimited strings are in fact parsed (for variable substitution), whereas single-quoted strings are not:

```
$var = 'Something';
echo "I want to echo $var";//output: I want to echo something
echo 'I want to echo $var';//output: I want to echo $var
```

Comment: You missed the fact that this string is already being echoed. Either he needs to exit php mode `?>` and escape as above, or use a ternary if, as i suggested

Comment: @Steve: I was busy editing my answer, added more info on the nested echo issue

Comment: Hi Elias, Ah, thanks for that, i have updated the question as above.

Comment: @MichaelGorman Yes, and I've commented. There's still a ton of issues to fix, so I've summed them up for you

Answer (score 0):

You cannot echo within an echo, instead use a ternary if:

```
echo('
    <option value="0" '. $fDetail['arrange']=="opening" ? 'selected="selected"':'' .'>opening</option>
    <option value="1" ' . $fDetail['arrange']=="closing" ? 'selected="selected"':'' .'>closing</option>
');
```

Comment: He's not trying to echo within echo?

Comment: @Naruto Yes he is, his question is poorly formated, but it begins `echo('...` i will edit it to better highlight that

Comment: Ow my apologies.. My eyes must have deceived me :)